# How to set up a private python package which can be installed from google colab

Tags: python, package, google-colaboratory, python-packaging

I want to install a private package on google colab. But it is not installing the correct versions and thus does not seem to work. I have the following in setup.cfg:

```
requests>=2
```

and this in requirements.txt:

```
requests=2.23.0
```

To download my package I run the following command:

```
!pip install git+https://****@github.com/mypackage.git

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting git+https://****@github.com/mypackage.git
  Cloning https://****@github.com/mypackage.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-h78dg_5o
  Running command git clone -q 'https://****@github.com/mypackage.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-h78dg_5o
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting requests>=2
  Downloading requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Installing collected packages: PyJWT, idna, cryptography, requests, typeform, msal, mypackage

  Attempting uninstall: requests
    Found existing installation: requests 2.23.0
    Uninstalling requests-2.23.0:
      Successfully uninstalled requests-2.23.0

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
google-colab 1.0.0 requires requests~=2.23.0, but you have requests 2.28.1 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed requests-2.28.1
```

As seen in the output, pip installs requests-2.28.1, eventhough 2.23.0 is specified in the requirements. It seems like it uses `requests>=2` to install the downloand and install the 2.28 version, uninstalling 2.23.

How should I change my package so the correct versions are downloaded?

**EDIT: After solving above problem I ran into something else:**

I am installing the following packages in my `setup.cfg`:

```
[options]
packages =
    package_1
    package_2
    package_3
```

This install 3 different packages on my local machine from which I can import modules. However, on google colab when I try:

```
import package_1

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-19-f86846990b2c> in <module>()
----> 1 import package_1

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/package_2/python_code.py in <module>()
----> 1 from package_2.more_code import a_function

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/package_2/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .resources import SomeCode

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_2.resources'


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

it seems it does not recognize package when referenced the second time, how is this possible?

Comment: When you `pip install` that way, `install_requires` from setup.py is used, not `requirements.txt`.

Comment: `requests>=0.0123,<2.24` - that should do it, I think.

Comment: ah that's it, adding `requests==2.23.0 to setup.cfg also works. Still trying to get my package to work though.